# Disable all controls of a table column using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow, rowid

I am looking to disable all the elements (controls) of specified table columns (td's) using jQuery.

My table looks like the following :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1.1.tcol"></td>
    <td id="1.2.tcol"></td>
    <td id="1.3.tcol"></td>
    <td id="1.4.tcol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="2.1.tcol"></td>
    <td id="2.2.tcol"></td>
    <td id="2.3.tcol"></td>
    <td id="2.4.tcol"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table is generated dynamically, but this is how it is rendered as. Now each of my `<td>` has multiple controls like select, checkbox, buttons, but not fixed for every row and column. I am looking to disable all controls of a specified `<td>` by using it's Id.

I used the following jQuery, but it doesn't seemt to do the job :

`$('#' + td_id).select('*').each(function(element){element.disabled=true});`

I have also tried the following, still it doesn't seem to work :

`$('#' + td_id).attr('disabled', 'false');`

Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('#' + td_id).find(':input').prop("disabled", true);
```

**[:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)** select all the input elements

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Also not all controls are of type 'input'. There are select dropdowns, textboxes, buttons, checkboxes.

Comment: pls check the link in the answer.. it does select all inputs elements

Comment: Oops...sorry. Didn't know that :input selects all the controls. Thought that it only selects types of input. But the code you provided doesn't disable. :(

Answer (score 0):

if you need to disable all controls in a column (multilpe rows) I think the best way is to assign a class to each `td` in that column.

For examle if you want to disable controls in the second column, you may do something similar:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1.1.tcol"></td>
    <td id="1.2.tcol" class="col-2"></td>
    <td id="1.3.tcol"></td>
    <td id="1.4.tcol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="2.1.tcol"></td>
    <td id="2.2.tcol" class="col-2"></td>
    <td id="2.3.tcol"></td>
    <td id="2.4.tcol"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Than, using JQuery you can do this:

```
$(".col-2 :input').prop("disabled", true);
```

It should work...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
<table>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <select>
        <option>1233</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <select>
        <option>second</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now to disable only first "td" you should use:

```
$('tr').children().eq(0).find(':input').prop("disabled", true);
```

If you are using JQuery1.6 or above use prop() else use attr().